# Confusion about __cvta_generic_to_shared

Tags: cuda, ptx

Nvidia Ampere GPU support feature: cp async from global mem to shared mem bypass L1 and register file.

The corresponding PTX core is `cp.async`.

Why need `__cvta_generic_to_shared`  to convert a shared mem ptr (T*) to `size_t`?

```cpp
size_t smem_a_converted = __cvta_generic_to_shared(smem_a);    

if(tid == 0 && bx == 0 && by == 0 && bz == 0){
    printf("addr check: %x, %x \n", smem_a, smem_a_converted);
}
```

Output: addr check: 1c001100, 7f92

Comment: Where is it stated that this conversion is needed?

Comment: It would be nice if you could provide a complete program, or at least a complete function with the PTX you were using.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the [PTX](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/index.html#state-spaces-types-and-variables) or machine code (SASS) level, CUDA GPUs have a system of state spaces, which is a partitioned addressing structure. `shared` is a state space.

An access to one of these state spaces can happen using either of two types of pointers: one that is decorated and appropriate for that space, and the other being a "generic" pointer.  A generic pointer does not carry any state or additional information to declare what state-space it belongs to.

In CUDA C++, like C++, pointers are pointers.  They have no additional decoration or meta information.

AFAIK, (although the conversion may be happening somewhere) the programmer need not worry about making the conversion explicitly when doing async copes using the C++-exposed [methods](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#asynchronous-data-copies).

However, the particular machine or PTX instructions that do this (async copy from global to shared) require a shared state-space pointer, not a generic pointer.

Therefore it is necessary to convert the C++-style generic pointer to the type that is needed for this instruction, if you were to extract the pointer from C++ but then issue the instruction via PTX, for example.  The `__cvta_generic_to_shared()` [method](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#cvta-generic-to-shared) is one possible way to [make this conversion](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/problem-about-ptx-instruction-cp-async-ca-shared-global/224219/2) in that case.

A state-space pointer in PTX or SASS has no real analog in C++, therefore the return type of `size_t` is used to identify the 64-bit quantity.  One might hesitate to use a C++ pointer quantity for it, because that would place it logically back into the "generic" realm.  There is no logical sense in which that pointer could be dereferenced in C++ to perform anything useful.

Comment: So shouldn't the return type be a `uint64_t`, for lack of a more appropriate type? And better perhaps also to advise OP to typedef an appropriate type name to `uint64_t` for this?

Comment: @einpoklum I think size_t(32bit, address up to 4GB) is enough for the address space of shared memory.

Comment: 1. The type needed here is an unsigned type that matches the pointer width of the underlying platform.  That is **exactly** the description of `size_t`.  2. Currently, there aren't any supported platforms for CUDA development that aren't 64-bit pointer based.  3. As demonstrated in one of my links, the shared state-space pointer seems to easily fit in 32 bits.